Docker network attach host network to custom network
Time to time I use ssh tunnel to map port to my local system. It could be postgres or mongo or someother service that I want to connect to.
I want to create a network that has a dns mapping with name like host-network which automatically points to my localhost (not the container). And since applications are running inside container I want to use host-network key to connect to my localhost where ssh tunnel is exposing port.
In case of mongodb the connection string would look like this
mongodb://username:mysecretpassword@host-network:27017/testDB?authSource=admin

I have a simple docker-compose file with a custom network. Take this as an example
version: "3.8"
networks:
  customnet:
    name: customnet

services:
  someapp:
    ....

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - customnet

Now how can I achieve this inside of customnet? I have tried adding below config to compose file but it doesn't work. I can do --net=host but I don't want to expose all ports to my local machine as It would defeat the purpose since I have multiple services running that are taking same ports.
extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

Can someone explain how to achieve this? I can attach other networks but I have never found solution to this. Here's how my ip addr looks. And if I am accurate I want to access lo network on here since ssh tunnel exposes to that network
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp55s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:bf:b8:c1:df:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.74/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp55s0
       valid_lft 73171sec preferred_lft 73171sec
    inet6 2400:1a00:b020:8303:b35d:9849:15ea:8ecb/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 843sec preferred_lft 843sec
    inet6 2400:1a00:b020:8303:abf:b8ff:fec1:dfbd/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 843sec preferred_lft 843sec
    inet6 fe80::abf:b8ff:fec1:dfbd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:89:4a:d3:a0:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
4: br-5ce4f697cffb: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:a0:59:dd:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-5ce4f697cffb
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-74391f9dab93: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:21:94:f2:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-74391f9dab93
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:21ff:fe94:f29e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:2e:1c:40:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


This sounds very similar to From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?  If you're on Docker Desktop then host.docker.internal will connect back to the host machine; if you're using the Docker engine directly then you need the extra_hosts: block you show.  You can't customize that name.  It's possible I'm confused – the ssh tunnel makes there be at least three different "localhosts" – what are you asking that's different?

@DavidMaze I am using docker engine installed with apt. I am asking for a way to add localhost as a dns name and then attaching that dns to the network I created. So that everything inside of that network can access using the name I provided. I also already went through that link for some reason maybe I am missing something but I wasn't able to connect to it. Only thing I could do was remove network and run in host mode

localhost is fixed to 127.0.0.1, and that IP address has a context-specific meaning.  In Docker it usually refers to the current container, and you need a different host name to refer to services that aren't running in the container.  You can't redefine what localhost means.

@DavidMaze let me clarify I don't care about  localhost name itself it can be asd or any other text as long as it maps to hosts localhost I am good. I just want that to attach to the network I created. The final result I want is to be able to use that connection string. Just like how docker-compose resolves service name as a dns name I want to resolve that custom string to connect to hosts localhost network where ssh tunnel will have port exposed

And you can't use host.docker.internal (on native Linux, via the extra_hosts: option you show)?

yes I am unable to do it. Maybe it's because of driver or something but I am unable to use that to connect to host machine
